# Scale 3D-Points in Plane

Tags: math, 3d, geometry

I have some points (3D) all on the same (known) plane. Now I want to scale these points within the plane as opposed to the whole 3D space.

Is there some quick solution for this e.g. a modified scaling matrix?
Can someone help me?

Thanks.

EDIT: I'm more looking for an idea/pseudocode how to do this. If you want use MatLab or some convenient language

Comment: How do you want to scale the points?

Comment: the same way you would scale (up/down) points in 2D-Space by a scalar.

Comment: You need to tell us what language you are using.

Comment: Does not really matter, CoffeeScript/JS just using Arrays as Points and 2D-Arrays with some utility as Matrices.

Comment: This is a very non-trivial problem for a general 3D plane.  I'd recommend rotating the plane onto the `xy`, `xz`, or `yz` axes, doing the scaling there, then rotating back.  And I'd recommend using Matlab or R for this rather than JavaScript.

Comment: Yes that's what I thought. I was hoping for a closed form solution e.g. a Matrix that does both the rotation and scaling.

Comment: I'd recommend asking this question again on the math Stack Exchange site.  You will probably get a theoretical answer, and maybe also an implementation you can use.  Stack Overflow is coding-heavy.

Comment: You could move all points by the vector -PlaneNormal * D (where D is plane distance from origin), apply scale, and then move back by PlaneNormal * D.

Comment: Plane distance from origin makes little sense since it's not constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your plane can be known by three non-collinear points `P0, P1, P2`, or by its implicit equation,

```
A.x + B.y + C.z + D = 0
```

In the first case, consider the vector `P0P1` and normalize it (`U = P0P1/|P0P1|`). Then compute a second vector orthogonal with the first, `V = P0P2 - (P0P2.U).U` and normalize it.

In the second case you can take the three intersection points with the axes, `(-D/A, 0, 0), (0, -D/B, 0), (0, 0, -D/C)` and you are back in the first case (but mind degenerate cases).

Use the two vectors to compute the desired 2D coordinates of any point `P = (X, Y, Z)` by the dot products

```
(x, y) = (P.U, P.V)
```

(This transform is a rotation that makes `P0P1` parallel to the `x` axis and brings `P0P1P2` in the plane `xy`.)

Comment: thanks, I managed to do this, projecting the points onto the xy plane, scale and project back. although the naming of your variables is a bit confusing

Comment: They should be read as vectors between two points, but indexes can't be typeset.